# Input 'input_image' of layer '63' not found in any of the outputs of the preceeding layers

Tags: pytorch, coreml, onnx, coremltools, onnx-coreml

### Update #1 *(original question and details below)*:

As per the suggestion of @MatthijsHollemans below I've tried to run this by removing `dynamic_axes` from the initial `create_onnx` step below. This removed both:

```sh
Description of image feature 'input_image' has missing or non-positive width 0.
```

and

```sh
Input 'input_image' of layer '63' not found in any of the outputs of the preceeding layers.
```

Unfortunately this opens up two sub-questions:

- I still want to have a functional ONNX model. Is there a more appropriate way to make H and W dynamic? Or should I be saving two versions of the ONNX model, one without `dynamic_axes` for the CoreML conversion, and one with for use as a valid ONNX model?
- Although this solves the compilation error in xcode (specified below) it introduces the following runtime issues:

```sh
Finalizing CVPixelBuffer 0x282f4c5a0 while lock count is 1.
[espresso] [Espresso::handle_ex_plan] exception=Invalid X-dimension 1/480 status=-7
[coreml] Error binding image input buffer input_image: -7
[coreml] Failure in bindInputsAndOutputs.
```

I am calling this the same way I was calling the fixed size model, which does still work fine. The image dimensions are 640 x 480.

As specified below the model should accept any image between 64x64 and higher.

**For flexible shape models, do I need to provide an input differently in xcode?**

---

### Original Question *(parts still relevant)*

I have been slowly working on converting a style transfer model from `pytorch > onnx > coreml`. One of the issues that has been a struggle is flexible/dynamic input + output shape.

This method (besides i/o renaming) has worked well on iOS 12 & 13 when using a static input shape.

I am using the following code to do the `onnx > coreml` conversion:

```py
def create_coreml(name):
    mlmodel = convert(
            model="onnx/" + name + ".onnx",
            preprocessing_args={'is_bgr': True},
            deprocessing_args={'is_bgr': True},
            image_input_names=['input_image'],
            image_output_names=['stylized_image'],
            minimum_ios_deployment_target='13'
            )

    spec = mlmodel.get_spec()

    img_size_ranges = flexible_shape_utils.NeuralNetworkImageSizeRange()

    img_size_ranges.add_height_range((64, -1))
    img_size_ranges.add_width_range((64, -1))

    flexible_shape_utils.update_image_size_range(
        spec,
        feature_name='input_image',
        size_range=img_size_ranges)

    flexible_shape_utils.update_image_size_range(
        spec,
        feature_name='stylized_image',
        size_range=img_size_ranges)

    mlmodel = coremltools.models.MLModel(spec)

    mlmodel.save("mlmodel/" + name + ".mlmodel")
```

Although the conversion 'succeeds' there are a couple of warnings (spaces added for readability):

```sh
Translation to CoreML spec completed. Now compiling the CoreML model.
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coremltools/models/model.py:111: 
RuntimeWarning: You will not be able to run predict() on this Core ML model. Underlying exception message was: 
Error compiling model: 
"Error reading protobuf spec. validator error: Description of image feature 'input_image' has missing or non-positive width 0.".
  RuntimeWarning)

Model Compilation done.
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coremltools/models/model.py:111: 
RuntimeWarning: You will not be able to run predict() on this Core ML model. Underlying exception message was: 
Error compiling model: 
"compiler error:  Input 'input_image' of layer '63' not found in any of the outputs of the preceeding layers.
".
  RuntimeWarning)
```

If I ignore these warnings and try to compile the model for latest targets (13.0) I get the following error in xcode:

```sh
coremlc: Error: compiler error:  Input 'input_image' of layer '63' not found in any of the outputs of the preceeding layers.
```

Here is what the problematic area appears to look like in netron:

[image]

---

***My main question is how can I get these two warnings out of the way?***

Happy to provide any other details.

Thanks for any advice!

---

Below is my `pytorch > onnx` conversion:

```py
def create_onnx(name):
    prior = torch.load("pth/" + name + ".pth")
    model = transformer.TransformerNetwork()
    model.load_state_dict(prior)

    dummy_input = torch.zeros(1, 3, 64, 64) # I wasn't sure what I would set the H W to here?

    torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "onnx/" + name + ".onnx",
                      verbose=True,
                      opset_version=10,
                      input_names=["input_image"], # These are being renamed from garbled originals.
                      output_names=["stylized_image"], # ^
                      dynamic_axes={'input_image':
                                    {2: 'height', 3: 'width'},
                                    'stylized_image':
                                    {2: 'height', 3: 'width'}}
                      )

    onnx.save_model(original_model, "onnx/" + name + ".onnx")
```

Comment: Does it work if you use a positive number for the upper bound instead of -1? So `(64, 128)` instead of `(64, -1)`?

Comment: Tested this now. 
`Description of image feature 'input_image' has missing or non-positive width 0` 
Happens at the `convert` step. So before I set the bounds. This data is coming straight from the onnx model. 

The second error still appears after changing -1 to a positive value.

Comment: Which is strange because in the `create_onnx` function above the `dummy_input` has H and W as positive values. I guess `dynamic_axes` are wiping that data and that's what convert sees in the next step.

Comment: Can you drop the `dynamic_axes` argument when doing the ONNX conversion? This might just be confusing things.

Comment: Thanks @MatthijsHollemans I've updated the top of the question above with the details of what that achieved. Tell me if any additional info can help.

Comment: I think you'll need to make two versions of the ONNX model indeed, where one is specific for Core ML conversion. As for the new error you're getting, does the model work with 640x480 when you remove the flexibility stuff and convert with 640x480 as the input size?

Comment: Just tested. The model does work as intended once I remove the flexibility.

Comment: Based on a suggestion in the ONNX gittr, I have also posted an issue on the onnx-coreml repo: https://github.com/onnx/onnx-coreml/issues/565

Comment: It seems like a bug in Core ML (and in the onnx-coreml converter possibly).

Comment: Hmm, that is unfortunate. I wish there was a way to diagnose the characteristics of this problem. I found someone else who has the same runtime error, but our models appear to not have the same issue: https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/276 Unfortunately their solution was to use Metal Performance Shaders. And I have no way to go forward in that direction.

Comment: Is not using a flexible input size an option? If you have the budget for it, you could also hire someone (like me) to convert the model to MPS.

Comment: It is an option in some applications but not in others, this model needs to be as flexible as possible. And under normal circumstances I would be able to hire someone, but this particular work is personal. Thanks for taking the time to look into this.

Comment: Something I would try is find out exactly which layer is causing problems. You can do this by manually removing layers from the mlmodel until the error goes away. It might be possible to replace the offending layer with something else. I recently did a project for a client where a Clip layer gave the wrong results on the GPU (but worked fine on CPU and ANE). By replacing just that one layer with a ReLU, the model also worked on the GPU. Obviously a bug in Core ML, but these kinds of workaround are the only solution for now.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try to do that over this weekend. Will update if I find the offending layer.